# Unable to modify UILabel frame inside UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

I have ViewController and inside it UICollectionView, I'm trying to add UILable to UICollectionView programmatically :

```
let Label: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Sample Text Here"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = UIColor(white: 0.4, alpha: 0.4)
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    return label
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    Label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: view.frame.width, height: 20)
    collectionView.addSubview(Label)
}
```

[image: where the label's position is not the same as x:0 , y: 40]

when I tried to change the y value it's the same

when I tried to add it like this : `view.addSubView(Label)` didn't appear at all.

note: the label should appear if there's no data to populate the cells

Comment: don't add subview to collectionView. Create UICollectionViewCell and add label to cell

Comment: @Bhanupriya the label will appear if there is no cells to populate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works..

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300), collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Sample Text Here"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = UIColor(white: 0.4, alpha: 0.4)
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)

    label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: view.frame.width, height: 20)
    collectionView.addSubview(label)

}
```

Be careful with adding labels directly to the collectionview, though. 
You could create a uiview and add both label to it and collection (with the appropriate collection view layout of course). Use collection view only for displaying cells and add anything to the cell.contentView if you wish

Thanks.